# Amazon SES: AWS SDK vs Query API

Tags: rest, amazon-web-services, https, aws-sdk, amazon-ses

I'm building a Ruby REST API app. If all it needs from the AWS SDK is the ability to send emails with Amazon SES, do I have to require the entire AWS SDK? Or, is there an easy way to only include what I need (SES)? Or, should I just use the Query API?

Comment: I don't think there's a way too just get the SES class out of there, but my 2 cents just roll with the gem. You can't go wrong and if you want to integrate more services later you can (which you probably will :D).

Comment: I am looking myself for an answer to this question, the AWS SDK documentation is a huge pile of mess! thus finding myself looking for using the API directly instead!